# Get HTML from Delta on Quill

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I am trying to get HTML code from delta on Quill.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
<link href="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <title>Editor</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="toolbar"></div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<script>

var toolbarOptions = [
['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
['blockquote', 'code-block'],
[{'header': 1}, {'header': 2}],
[{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
[{'script': 'sub'}, {'script': 'super'}],
[{'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
[{'direction': 'rtl'}],
[{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],
['link', 'image', 'video', 'formula'],
[{'color': []}, {'background': []}],
[{'font': []}],
[{'align': []}]
];
var options = {
  debug: 'info',
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  placeholder: 'Textttt',
  readOnly: false,
  theme: 'snow'
};
var editor = new Quill('#editor', options);
    var delta = quill.getContents();
function quillGetHTML(inputDelta) {
    var tempCont = document.createElement("div");
    (new Quill(tempCont)).setContents(inputDelta);
    return tempCont.getElementsByClassName("ql-editor")[0].innerHTML;
}
function callMe(){
$(document).ready(function(){$("#btn1").click(function(){$("p").append(quillGetHTML(delta));});});}
</script>
<p>HTML: </p>
<button id="btn1" onClick="callMe()">Get HTML From Delta</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on the button, nothing appears, I checked `callMe()` function and it works, this means that the problem is extracting HTML from delta.

Comment: You can probably build you solution on top of this: https://gist.github.com/ninetyone/73b927dc0fff012a1f4892460aa46bde

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes you're right, extracting HTML not work, but the problem is quill refuse to support `getHTML()` function. https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/903

But you can use `quill.root.innerHTML`. Try this:

http://jsbin.com/zuniqef

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <!-- Main Quill library -->
<script src="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme included stylesheets -->
<link href="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.0/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>

  <div id="toolbar"></div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<script>

var toolbarOptions = [
['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
['blockquote', 'code-block'],
[{'header': 1}, {'header': 2}],
[{'list': 'ordered'}, {'list': 'bullet'}],
[{'script': 'sub'}, {'script': 'super'}],
[{'indent': '-1'}, {'indent': '+1'}],
[{'direction': 'rtl'}],
[{'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge']}],
['link', 'image', 'video', 'formula'],
[{'color': []}, {'background': []}],
[{'font': []}],
[{'align': []}]
];
var options = {
  debug: 'info',
  modules: {
    toolbar: toolbarOptions
  },
  placeholder: 'Textttt',
  readOnly: false,
  theme: 'snow'
};
var editor = new Quill('#editor', options);
  editor.insertText(0, 'Hello', 'bold', true);//set init value
function callMe() //display current HTML
  {
    var html = editor.root.innerHTML;
    alert(html);
  }
</script>
<div>HTML: </div>
<button id="btn1" onClick="callMe()">Get HTML From Delta</button>

</body>
</html>
```

If this editor (quill) is not support getHTML (which is important for future use). I recommend you to use another text editor library like: ckeditor which my best recommendation in 4 years used it (absolutely I try many text editors too in that period).

Comment: if this code not work, let me know that. because i never use quill (first time use it now)

Comment: editor.root.innerHTML is already escaped? When a user uses <script> tag and we save that to the db and reload it, it doesn't run the javascript right?

Comment: 1+ for recommending ckeditor. It's such an easy rich text editor even for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 6):

I just use - **$("#form").find('#quill-editor .ql-editor').html();**

where #form is the containing form of your editor...

Comment: It's not the most elegant solution, but works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

in order to get any extra spaces the user has inserted, I use

`this.editor.root.innerHTML.split('  ').join(' &nbsp;')`

(note, there are two spaces in the `split` and one space in the `join`!)

Comment: Appreciate this note about spaces — I almost forgot to keep them (people still use them for formatting tables!)