# How to insert HTML plain text into DB?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am creating PHP source code, which inserts page I have created using quill text editor. Text editor data is inserting work, but not inserting plain text.
I want to insert HTML plain text

Here is my  JavaScript code

```
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.3/quill.core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.3/quill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.2.2/quill.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script>
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic'],
      ['link', 'blockquote', 'code-block', 'image'],
      [{ list: 'ordered' }, { list: 'bullet' }]
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'
});

var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  // Populate hidden form on submit
  var about = document.querySelector('input[name=content]');
  about.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());


};
</script>
```

Display like this results

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"},{"attributes":{"code-block":true},"insert":"\n"}]}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST);` show? If that's what it looks like in your variable, that's what you are going to see when you insert it into your database.

Comment: There is a typo in `script>setTimeout`

Comment: I understand this is outside the scope of the question, but you are potentially opening your users to some really, really nasty security risks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get HTML from Delta on Quill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058551/get-html-from-delta-on-quill)

Comment: And what is inserted to your database ?

Comment: is this code risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **InnerHTML** and not using **jSON.Stringify**

```
about.value = quill.root.innerHTML;
```

Comment: @previn no problem: if it’s working hit that little up arrow next the answer and then accept the answer